# Constness problems in c_str() function in custom string implementation

Tags: c++

Still new to C++. I'm trying to implement c_str() function. I tried:

```
class Str
{

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef char* iterator;
    typedef const char* const_iterator;

const char* c_str() const {
    char* tmp = alloc.allocate(length + 1);
    alloc.construct(tmp + length + 1, '\0');
    for(size_type i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        tmp[i] = data[i];

    return tmp;
}

private:
    char* data;
    size_type length;

    std::allocator<char> alloc;
};
```

but my compiler is complaining. It seems that, because of defining function as const, allocate() must return const pointer (or I got something wrong). Anyway, this is not working and I want to know what's the case.

1) I know that I call allocate(), but I call it on new variable, not the member of a Str. That's why I don't get that part.
2) I know about "return data", but I wanted to know why this won't work. In C++11, there's no difference between c_str() and data(), but let's say there still is: How would I make difference between those two if I always do "return data;"?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: since your function is `const` you cannot call non-const methods on your members, i.e. `alloc.allocate`

Comment: Well, the method is `const`, but you call `alloc.allocate` and `alloc.construct`, which are non-const. You can't do that. But I don't see the point of your function anyway. I can't see why a scring class would want to return an allocated string to the caller, especially if the caller has no idea how to de-allocate it. You really don't want to "fix" the errors, you need a different approach.

Comment: just something to consider: `.c_str()` is supposed to be O(1) for a reason, in most string implementations it returns a `const` pointer directly to the internal buffer. Your implementation will leak memory.

Comment: `return data;` would make rather more sense than this inefficient leak factory.

Comment: 1) I know that I call allocate(), but I call it on new variable, not the member of a Str. That's why I don't get that part.
2) I know about "return data", but I wanted to know why this won't work. In C++11, there's no difference between c_str() and data(), but let's say there still is: How would I make difference between those two if I always do "return data;"?

Comment: @Bade 1) what new variable?! 2) see the first part of my answer

Comment: @Bade: please include new facts and following questions in the body od the text, or post them as new questions. "Comments" may allow to have a quick good chat, but they are very limited. Next time, please just re-edit your post and reshape and expand it. Of course, there are some limits, you should'nt erase it and replace with wholly different thing, especially if there are already some answers. But I hope you get the point. I pasted your new following questions at the end of the post. Please feel free to adjust them further!

Comment: You are calling `allocate` on a member of `Str` called `alloc`.

Comment: @Bade: (but _of course_ if they are **new questions** - post a new question instead of infinitely expanding the original one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `c_str()` is done by all known implementations of `std::string` is to reserve space for one additional character in `data` and keep it null terminated at all times, so that `c_str()` is simply `return data;` and that is guaranteed to already be null-terminated.

> It seems that, because of defining function as const, allocate() must return const pointer (or I got something wrong).

No, you definitely got something wrong.

The problem in your code is that `alloc` is const in that member function. You can solve it by making a non-const copy of the allocator:

```
const char* c_str() const {
    std::allocator<char> alloc2(alloc);
    char* tmp = alloc2.allocate(length + 1);
    alloc2.construct(tmp + length + 1, '\0');
    for(size_type i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        tmp[i] = data[i];

    return tmp;
}
```

This doesn't make the function correct, because it allocates memory every time you call it, so the caller must free it using `std::allocator<char>`, that is **not** the correct interface for `c_str()`!

N.B. using `std::allocator<char>::construct` is utterly pointless, you might as well just do `tmp[length] = '\0'`. Even using `std::allocator<char>` is pretty pointless, you can just use `new` and `delete[]`. The reason to use an allocator is to allow users to customise it with alternative allocators, but if you're just going to fix it to only use `std::allocator<char>` there's no real advantage to using an allocator at all, and you're just making your class take up more space to store the pointless `alloc` member.

Also, shouldn't this be `tmp + length`?

```
    alloc.construct(tmp + length + 1, '\0');
```

**Responding to the edited questions**:

> 1) I know that I call allocate(), but I call it on new variable, not the member of a Str. That's why I don't get that part.

Erm, no you don't, you call it on a member!

> 2) I know about "return data", but I wanted to know why this won't work. In C++11, there's no difference between c_str() and data(), but let's say there still is: How would I make difference between those two if I always do "return data;"?

Why do you want to make a difference between the two?

C++03 doesn't say there *must* be a difference between the two, it's conforming for them to be identical, and one of the reasons `c_str()` and `data()` are exactly the same in C++11 is *that's how all implementations did it in C++03 anyway*. It's really the only sane way to do it.

Making them different for no reason just makes it extremely difficult to implement `c_str()` and so is a very silly design choice.

Comment: 1) I thought allocate() will take value of length and return non-const pointer. So, I thought it won't change value of lenght.
2) c_str() was implemented (before) as to return null-terminated const char* and data() to return const char* that is not null-terminated.

Comment: Or you talking about changing the alloc member? Sorry for being slow on this.

Comment: I'm talking about **this:** `alloc.allocate(length + 1);` -- that calls a **non-const** function on `alloc`, which is a **member of your class** so you cannot do non-const things to it in a const member function!

Comment: _"`c_str()` was implemented (before) as to return null-terminated `const char*` and `data()` to return `const char*` that is not null-terminated. "_ No, no, no, that is wrong. Nothing in the old C++ standard said that the string returned by `data()` **must not be** null-terminated. It gave you a pointer that compared equal to the characters in the string, nothing forbids it from also having an additional nul character at the end. It was always allowed for `data()` to be exactly the same as `c_str()` **and that's what all known implementations always did**.

Answer (score 0):

why not return data as const char* ? no one can change it since it const.

```
const char* c_str() const{
   return data;
}
```

Comment: Correct and valid suggestion, better as a comment though.

Comment: sorry, but your answer does not actually answer the question (assuming that the question was "I want to know what's the case")

Comment: That is most likely correct, unless the OP does not use a null character to terminate the `data` string, in which case the returned pointer will not be usable.

Comment: Yes, the reason not to do that is the OP's `Str` class doesn't keep `data` null-terminated, and the OP doesn't realise that it would make much more sense to keep `data` null-terminated for exactly this reason.